COMPUTE STATS IMPALA results in DiskErrorException
I'm trying to execute a compute stats (COMPUTE STATS db.table;) on one of my tables via IMPALA (on a ClouderaDataPlatform), but for this table only I'm encountering the following error:
RuntimeIOException: 
Failed to create file: s3a://<my-bucket>/<my-path>/<db_name>.db/<table_name>/metadata/<uuid>.metadata.json
CAUSED BY: 
DiskErrorException: Could not find any valid local directory for s3ablock-0001- 
with requested size 67108864 as the max capacity in any directory is 0

While searching for a solution the only links I found dealt with spark, kafka, hadoop or some variations, from which I couldn't find a situation akin to mine.
I understand that this might be due to a simple setting that needs to be configured properly, or maybe even a question of privileges (doubtful), but I can't figure out which setting might be involved.
Any help woud be greatly appreciated.
impalad version 4.0.0.7.2.17.200-29

the hadoop docs are the ones to use, because the s3a connector is from that codebase. Especially the troubleshooting s3a section
Could not find any valid local directory for s3ablock-0001- 
with requested size 67108864 as the max capacity in any directory is 0

one of

you have no disk space
fs.s3a.buffer.dir isn't valid. it MUST be a non-empty list of local fs directory; e.g /tmp/s3a


Thank you for your pointers. I'll try invetigate in these directions
